# How to change the colour automatically?

Tags: excel, formatting

As you can see in this picture, how to make the column will automatically change to the colour black when all they already reach 1000? And the colour will change to black right after the number that already reach 1000. Is there any solution for this? Because right now, I'm doing it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select all numerical value > Home > conditional formatting > highlight cell .. "Equal to" > set:1000,fill formatting.

hope it helps.

Comment: sorry.. just noticed that "greater than 1000" is false when the value is exactly 1000..

Comment: I had updated my ans... had you tested it on a new excel file?

Comment: yes, already tested it. it only highlight at the number 1000 instead of highlight the column after reach 1000

Comment: which cell did you select for "select all numerical value " ? || you should select all cells from A3 downwards...

Comment: wait, i try first.

Comment: i already did as what you asked, but still it only change the colour at column 1k.

Comment: where is "column 1k" ?... are you referring to column ALL1 ?

Comment: as you can see the picture in the comment, the total number in row 52 is 1k. so, what I want to do is after the total already reach 1k, the column after it will be in black colour. so in the picture, at line 52, I want black column after 650.

Comment: Sorry.. my solution doesn't work.. I tried to put in this formula [ `=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("R"&CELL("row")&"C1",FALSE):INDIRECT("R"&CELL("row")&"C"&(CELL("col")-1),FALSE))>=1000,TRUE,FALSE)` ] into the conditional formatting but it returns an error message instead. "-_-